# Hydration error testing with Cypress, and react

Tags: javascript, cypress, remix.run

I'm trying to use cypress with remix and got the below error when using cypress with it for the first time. I don't get these errors outside of using cypress. (I'm using cypress with remix as these errors appear on any page I've tried so far

`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

My cypress config is:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress"

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const isDev = config.watchForFileChanges
      const port = process.env.PORT ?? (isDev ? "3000" : "8811")
      const configOverrides: Partial<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> = {
        baseUrl: `http://localhost:${port}`,
        video: !process.env.CI,
        screenshotOnRunFailure: !process.env.CI,
      }

      
      on("task", {
        log: (message) => {
          console.log(message)

          return null
        },
      })

      return { ...config, ...configOverrides }
    },
  },
}
```

example test which errors (although they all do):

```js
describe("Wizard", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/wizard")
  })

  it("goes through wizard", () => {
    cy.findByRole("button", { name: /U17/i }).click()
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27204?

Comment: Thanks very helpful... updated in the answer below for others.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting the below into cypress/e2e.ts to suppress the errors and the tests will work again. Ultimately this is an issue in react affecting a number of other browser plugins such as cypress.

More context and source here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27204#issuecomment-1894217901

```js
Cypress.on("uncaught:exception", (err) => {
  // Cypress and React Hydrating the document don't get along
  // for some unknown reason. Hopefully, we figure out why eventually
  // so we can remove this.
  // https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/4822#issuecomment-1679195650
  // https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27204
  if (
    /hydrat/i.test(err.message) ||
    /Minified React error #418/.test(err.message) ||
    /Minified React error #423/.test(err.message)
  ) {
    return false
  }
}
```